# Plot the intersection of a plane with the volume of a function

Tags: plotting, visualization, intersection

I have the following function:

```
r1[x_, y_] := 25.029205084016887* E^(0.07848246*-68.66347844300994 - 0.005271437722209233*(53.03569084 + -68.66347844300994 + 6.37084885* Log[(6.768705880738582 - x)^2 + (1.2337283006959585 - y)^2])^2);
```

and three points that define a plane:

```
A := {4.514129804574033, -1.323657939915483, 0};
B := {4.514129804574033, -1.323657939915483, 20000};
C1 := {6.768705880738582, 1.2337283006959585, 0};
```

I want to plot only the intersection between the plane and the volume of this function (above the plane of XY origin). For example, the slice* below the red intersection curve that you see in the following picture:

[image: Intersection Curve]

*A slice looking something like that:

[image: Slice]

I thought it would be very easy but after a full day of failing.. I decided to reach here for help!

Answer (score 3):

Note your plane is perpendicular to the x/y plane. Therefore, the y value only depends on x. We can define a function `y[x]` by requesting that the line goes through A and C1:

```
eq = {A[[1]] cx + c0 == A[[2]], C1[[1]] cx + c0 == C1[[2]]};
y[x_] = cx x + c0 /. Solve[eq, {cx, c0}][[1]]
```

We may now plot the surface of r1 and combine it with a plot of the parametrized line: {x,y[x],r1[x,y[x]]}:

```
Show[{Plot3D[r1[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 50],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, y[x], r1[x, y[x]]}, {x, -20, 20},PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

[image: ![]

**Addendum:**

You may use `ImplicitPlot` but you have to scale r1 as this is not done automatically:

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[{0 <= z <= 100 r1[x, y] && 
    y == fy[x] && -20 < x < 20 && -20 < y < 20}, {x, y, z}], 
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, to have a line there (instead of what I had managed to have is nice), yet what I wanted was to plot the intersection area of the plane with the volume of that function. So  r1 would be gone and only a slice (not only the red curve) of that would be visible.

Comment: @Gouz I added the intersection area, but note you need to scale the plot by hand.

Answer (score 2):

One possible method.

```
section = 
 ContourPlot3D[({x, y, z} - B) . Cross[A - B, C1 - B] == 0, {x, -20, 
   20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -.1, .2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= z <= r1[x, y]], 
  PlotPoints -> 80, ContourStyle -> Blue, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionBoundaryStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Yellow], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Another way maybe as below.

```
reg = RegionIntersection[InfinitePlane[{A, B, C1}], 
   ImplicitRegion[
    z <= r1[x, y], {{x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -.1, .2}}]];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
  BaseStyle -> Red]
```

[image]